# Inequalities on quotient of differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $f_1,f_2:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be two differentiable functions. Suppose that $f_1$ is linear and that $$\frac{f_1(b)}{f_1(a)}>\frac{f_2(b)}{f_2(a)}>1$$
I need to verify when the following inequality
$$\frac{f_1(b_1)}{f_1(a_1)}\ge\frac{f_2(b_1)}{f_2(a_1)}$$
is verified for every $a_1,b_1\in[a,b]$, $a_1<b_1$. But I'm not able to find a sufficient condition on $f_1,f_2$. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\frac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)}$, then the given inequality is equivalent to $g(x)$ being monotonically increasing:

$$\frac{f_1(b_1)}{f_1(a_1)}\ge\frac{f_2(b_1)}{f_2(a_1)} \quad\iff\quad \frac{f_1(b_1)}{f_2(b_1)}\ge\frac{f_1(a_1)}{f_2(a_1)} \quad\iff\quad g(b_1) \ge g(a_1) \;\;\text{for}\;\; b_1 \gt a_1$$

Since the functions are differentiable and positive, $g$ is increasing iff $\ln g = \ln f_1 - \ln f_2$ is increasing, or $(\ln g)' \ge 0\,$, which gives the necessary and sufficient condition:

$$\big(\ln f_2(x)\big)' \le \big(\ln f_1(x)\big)'\quad\iff\quad \frac{f_2'(x)}{f_2(x)} \le \frac{f_1'(x)}{f(x)} $$